# В чем разница между RTSP, RTMP, HLS?

Tags: android, видео, rtmp, hls, rtsp

В чем разница между RTSP, RTMP, HLS ? Надо получить видео поток без минимальной задержки. Приложение под android, а на android как знаю с RTMP проблемы. Но есть RTSP и HLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница `RTMP/RTSP/HLC` в спецификациях интерфейсов, по сути одно и тоже, ТОЛЬКО В ПРОФИЛЬ.

`RTMP` - это перекодированный с `RTSP` поток во `Flash Media`.

`HLC` - это `http` обвертка `UDP` потока...

Рекомендую использовать `HLC`, так как он более адаптивен. `RTSP` спецификацию не меняли лет 5-6. Много косяков, рассчитан больше не стриминг, нежели `upload`.

Comment: Ну ничего себе одно и то же